# Data Cleansing in Python/Pandas All Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a csv with 100 columns. Due to the data structure NULLs are represented as '----' of varying lengths. 
Is it possible convert all fields/columns where the first 2 characters of the field are '--' to NULL at the same time?

Comment: Can you add data sample, 5rows, 4 columns, what you try and expected output?

Comment: So need replace only fields with `2` and more `-`? So `--a` is necessary replace to `NAN`? And `aa--` not? Or both?

Comment: --a would be replaced with NaN but not aa--. As long as the field starts with atleast 2 '--'

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.replace` with `regex=True`

**Ex:**

```
df = df.replace("^--", np.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: And better , explain why replace partial of string , and whole string become np.nan

Comment: @Wen - Added to comment, maybe try add another if not nice;)